# AspectJ does not execute advice on reflection

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
    @MyAnnotation
    public void someMethod() {

    }
}
```

In the advice for the pointcut, I am basically extracting the 'Method' that the annotation is for. Then, the method is delegated to one of the many handlers for it depending on some configuration.

At this point, I must point out, that the source of all trouble is that I can't really do a `joinPoint.proceed()` in the advice. `Method.invoke()` kind of needs to happen on the method because there is another delegate that in a parallel thread keeps on invoking that said method, and the execution of that doesn't have a `ProceedingJoinPoint`.

The problem is that, whenever I do a `Method.invoke()` on `someMethod`, the advice runs again (of course), since it has the annotation on it. This causes it to run again and again and again.

I need to way to either:

1. Don't run the advice if invoked by reflections or Method.invoke (I don't really think it is possible).
2. Detect, within the advice, if the call is from one of the delegates.

For #2, I considered setting up a flag or something, but that doesn't keep it thread-safe anymore.

Any suggestions?

A more clarified code example:

I have a defined Aspect:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@com.rohanprabhu.annotation.Process * *(..)) "
        + "&& @annotation(process)")
public void processPointcut(Process process) {
}

@Around("processPointcut(process)")
public Object process(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Process process)
        throws Throwable {
    final Object callingObject = joinPoint.getThis();
    final Method method = ((MethodSignature)joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
    final MethodContext methodContext = new MethodContext(callingObject, method);

    //The below mentioned delegate will be picked
    //depending on some validation performed on 'callingObject'
    Object retValue = delegate.process(methodContext, joinPoint.getArgs());
    return retValue;
}
```

And a delegate looks like this:

```
class SimpleDelegate extends Delegate {
    @Override
    public Object process(final MethodContext methodContext, final Object[] args) {
        // The problem is that following invoke call calls
        // the @Around aspect to run again, which calls the delegate again,
        // which causes execution of the next line, which causes the aspect to run
        // again and so on...
        methodContext.getMethod().invoke(
            methodContext.getCallingObject(),
            args
        );
    }
}
```

It would be great if I could do something like (I really don't think there is something like `calledByReflection`:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@com.rohanprabhu.annotation.Process * *(..)) "
        + "&& @annotation(process)" + " && !calledByReflection")
public void processPointcut(Process process) {
}
```

Or something like:

```
@Around("processPointcut(process)")
public Object process(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Process process,
               final boolean processAnnotation)
        throws Throwable {
    if(processAnnotation) {
        // Do the regular stuff
    }
}
```

and there was some way for me to supply the value to `processAnnotation` to the Aspect. I hope this clarified my question.
    }

Comment: I think I can help you. I have an educated guess about what you mean, but to double-check, please provide a minimal, but complete code sample (Java + aspect code) which reproduces the problematic behaviour. If I was at home I could play around myself, but on the road with only an iPad I need more input.

Comment: Hey. Thank you so much for offering to help. I have added more code examples and even imaginary code as to how a solution would look like (offering a peek inside my head, maybe?). Thank you once again.

Comment: You could use call() instead of execution() for your pointcut (assuming you're not using spring-aop).  I don't think that would apply to reflective calls.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That totally worked. If you would have posted it an answer, I would have marked it as the correct one. In the meantime, have an upvote on the comment :) (If you would still post it an answer, I would love to mark it as the correct solution). Thank you so much once again...